# MS-Access 2003 SQL ALike modification not working

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I have a query that pulls vacation time Gained, Used, and Left by employee.  I have since modified the ALike statement on the "Gain" To look for "Anniversary" Then return the value. It now returns 0 the fail statement for the Iif.  Here is the SQL.

```
SELECT 
       SchedulingLog.UserID, 
       SchedulingLog.Category, 
       Sum(IIf([CatDetail] ALike 'Anniversary*',[Value],0)) AS Gain, 
       Sum(IIf(CatDetail ALike '%Used',[Value],0)) AS Used, [Gain]+[Used] AS [Left]
FROM SchedulingLog
GROUP BY SchedulingLog.UserID, SchedulingLog.Category
HAVING (((SchedulingLog.Category) Like "Vac*"));
```

Comment: You are working purely in MS Access using the standard ANSI SQL set-up, is that correct? If so, there is no need to complicate things with ALike, just use Like and the standard wildcard.

Comment: Simple and effective!!! State that as the answer please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working purely in MS Access using the standard ANSI SQL set-up, is that correct? If so, there is no need to complicate things with ALike, just use Like and the standard wildcard *.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using Alike you would use the ANSI wildcard (%) instead of Jet's default (*).

So

```
WHERE FieldName Like 'Something*'
```

would be

```
WHERE FieldName ALike 'Something%'
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.  I think you want 'Anniversary%' and 'Vac%'
I'd recommend using the like function vs the alike function.  I've read that access does support alike through ADO connections, but it is not documented that I could find.

Verify that CatDetail contains data in the form 'AnniversaryXXXXX' in your source table,  you may need to modify it to '%Anniversary%' if the column does not always start with the 'Anniversary'